# Removing mxgraph connection and label handles?

Tags: javascript, mxgraph

I'm having a hard time finding what I need in the documentation.  I know there are constants, but can't seem to find one that will do what I want.

I wish to make mxGraph so that you cannot unconnect an edge connection handle to a vertex.  I do not want them to show.  Additionally, the label handle, I wish to remove.

How would I do this?

```
function main(container) {

    // Enables rotation handle
    mxVertexHandler.prototype.rotationEnabled = false;
    mxVertexHandler.prototype.guidesEnabled = false;

    // Alt disables guides
    mxGuide.prototype.isEnabledForEvent = function(evt) {
        return !mxEvent.isAltDown(evt);
    };


    // Enables snapping waypoints to terminals
    mxEdgeHandler.prototype.snapToTerminals = true;


    // Checks if the browser is supported
    if (!mxClient.isBrowserSupported()) {
        console.log('flip to the browser compatiability message');
    }

    // Disables built-in context menu
    mxEvent.disableContextMenu(document.body);

    // Changes some default colors
    mxConstants.HANDLE_FILLCOLOR = '#99ccff';
    mxConstants.HANDLE_STROKECOLOR = '#0088cf';
    mxConstants.VERTEX_SELECTION_COLOR = '#00a8ff';

    // Creates the graph inside the given container
    var graph = new mxGraph(container);
    var parent = graph.getDefaultParent();



    var baseStyle = graph.getStylesheet().getDefaultVertexStyle();
    var edgeStyle = graph.getStylesheet().getDefaultEdgeStyle();

    // setup style
    style = mxUtils.clone(baseStyle);
    style[mxConstants.STYLE_EDITABLE] = 0;
    style[mxConstants.STYLE_FILLCOLOR] = "#ffffff";
    style[mxConstants.STYLE_STROKECOLOR] = "#d4d4d4";
    style[mxConstants.STYLE_STROKEWIDTH] = 1;
    style[mxConstants.STYLE_ROUNDED] = 1;
    style[mxConstants.STYLE_ARCSIZE] = 10;
    style[mxConstants.STYLE_RESIZABLE] = 0;
    style[mxConstants.STYLE_MARGIN] = 50;
    graph.getStylesheet().putCellStyle("style", style)

    edgeStyle[mxConstants.STYLE_EDITABLE] = 0;
    edgeStyle[mxConstants.STYLE_RESIZABLE] = 0;
    edgeStyle[mxConstants.STYLE_STROKECOLOR] = "#d4d4d4";
    edgeStyle[mxConstants.STYLE_ORTHOGONAL] = 0;
    edgeStyle[mxConstants.STYLE_STROKEWIDTH] = 1;
    edgeStyle[mxConstants.STYLE_BENDABLE] = 1;
    edgeStyle[mxConstants.STYLE_ROUNDED] = true;
    edgeStyle[mxConstants.STYLE_EDGE] = mxConstants.EDGESTYLE_ENTITY_RELATION;
    edgeStyle[mxConstants.LABEL_HANDLE_SIZE] = 50;
    edgeStyle[mxConstants.HANDLE_FILLCOLOR] = '#000000'
    graph.getStylesheet().putCellStyle("edge_style", edgeStyle);

    try {
        var v1 = graph.insertVertex(parent, null, 'One', 20, 20, 80, 30, 'style');
        var v2 = graph.insertVertex(parent, null, 'Two', 200, 150, 80, 30, 'style');
        var v3 = graph.insertVertex(parent, null, 'Three', 460, 20, 80, 30, 'style');

        var e1 = graph.insertEdge(parent, null, 'connected', v1, v2, "edge_style");
        var e2 = graph.insertEdge(parent, null, 'connected', v1, v3, "edge_style");
        var e4 = graph.insertEdge(parent, null, 'connected', v3, v2, "edge_style");

        // TODO: make it so only the root cell can't be moved
        graph.isCellLocked = function(cell) {
            return false;
        }

        // can't resize cells
    } finally {
        graph.getModel().endUpdate();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

This function will restrict Edges to stick to Vertices and not to move freely.

```
graph.setAllowDanglingEdges(false);
```

Try this one.